# access SQL package with transposing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I decided to share one with you my dataset in an excel file attached, it is composed of 3 tabs, each tab represents a table + a 4th tab that represents the expected result.

the designation table is initially a relation that has become a table so it registers IDbeneficiaire + IDcontrat

Frankly I lost 2 days on that and I still can not do this on Access, I need this result for next week in an automatic way on Access. can you help me get this result with a SQL access request please

[enter link description here](https://www.cjoint.com/c/HDgkpUKE1vJ)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The link is working. Click the top (red) button to download his file.